# Can you set background-image CSS property of an element from an imported image in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have an Angular component where I need to set the background image of the `ion-content` element that wraps the component. I have done this in my scss file like this:

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url('^path/to/my/image.png');
}
```

This used to work fine while my component was a part of the host-app project. However, we have now switched to a micro-frontend architecture and now it can no longer resolve the path to our assets in this manner. With images I use in my template I import them in the TypeScript file and use the imported image in the template:

```
import backgroundImage from 'path/to/my/image.png';
```

Now, I can get the `ion-content` element in my TypeScript file, but is there a way to set the use the imported image to set the `background-image` since it normally takes a path in the `url(...)`?

Comment: You can use `backgroundImage: url(${backgroundImage})` in your template

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Unfortunately this is not an option since I don't have access to `ion-content` in my template.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

In my scss file:

```
ion-content {
  background-image: var(--background-image);
}
```

And then im my TypeScript file I do this:

```
import backgroundImage from 'path/to/my/image.png';

const content = document.querySelector('ion-content');
content?.style.setProperty(
  '--background-image',
  `url('${backgroundImage}')`
);
```